# flutter params array getting stringified on api request

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter dart am making an API call like below

```
  Future<dynamic> fetchInstitutionsCall() {
      List<int> requestedItemsList =[18,5];
      return ApiManager.instance.makeApiCall(
        callName: 'fetchInstitutions',
        apiUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/api/v1/find_institutions/',
        callType: ApiCallType.GET,
        params: {
          'user': 'sam',
          'requested_items': requestedItemsList,
        },
        returnResponse: true,
      );
    }
```

The above request when received in server is received as a string instead of an array for the `requested_items` params like below

```
Parameters: {"user"=>"sam", "requested_items"=>"[18,5]"}
```

But the server is expecting in below format

```
 Parameters:  {"user"=>"sam", "requested_items"=>["18", "5"]}
```

How can we send a request in flutter so that `requested_items` params `array` won't get `stringified` when received in server?

Thank you

Comment: post the makeApiFunction definition as well, for better understanding, because I think the `params` is getting converted just before making the api call.